# UILabel and UIActivityIndicatorView centered in visible area of UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel, uiactivityindicatorview

I am adding a UILabel and UIActivityIndicatorView as a subview to a tableview as a loading indicator. I want these items to be in the middle of the visible are of the table view, and remain in the center if the user scrolled, so the user will always see the items. My code to create them is:

```
if (!spinner) {
        spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]      initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
        [spinner startAnimating];

        loadingLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        loadingLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];
        loadingLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        loadingLabel.text = @"Loading...";
        [loadingLabel sizeToFit];

        static CGFloat bufferWidth = 8.0;

        CGFloat totalWidth = spinner.frame.size.width + bufferWidth + loadingLabel.frame.size.width;

        CGRect spinnerFrame = spinner.frame;
        spinnerFrame.origin.x = (self.tableView.bounds.size.width - totalWidth) / 2.0;
        spinnerFrame.origin.y = (self.tableView.bounds.size.height - spinnerFrame.size.height) / 2.0;
        spinner.frame = spinnerFrame;
        spinner.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin);
        [self.tableView addSubview:spinner];

        CGRect labelFrame = loadingLabel.frame;
        labelFrame.origin.x = (self.tableView.bounds.size.width - totalWidth) / 2.0 + spinnerFrame.size.width + bufferWidth;
        labelFrame.origin.y = (self.tableView.bounds.size.height - labelFrame.size.height) / 2.0;
        loadingLabel.frame = labelFrame;
        loadingLabel.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin);
        [self.tableView addSubview:loadingLabel];
    }
```

How can I make it recenter when the table view scrolls?

**EDIT**

How would I calculate the sizes to reposition the spinner to the middle? What property would I set?

Comment: Is it UIViewController or UITableViewController?

Comment: It is a UITableViewController in which the above code is running, and the table view is where the label/activity indicator should show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add your view to the superview of the table view (if possible; `UITableViewController`makes this impossible)
2. Add your view to the table view and reposition it in the `-scrollViewDidScroll:`delegate method (`UITableViewDelegate`is a sub-protocol of `UIScrollViewDelegate`)

**EDIT**:

For maintaining center of the view

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{ 

CGSize adSize = [awView actualAdSize]; 

CGRect newFrame = awView.frame; newFrame.origin.x = (self.view.bounds.size.width - adSize.width)/2; 

newFrame.origin.y = (self.tableView.contentOffset.y - adSize.height/2) -21; 

awView.frame = newFrame; 
}
```

Comment: How would I do the math to calculate what the center of the current visible area is? I am a little bit confused about frame, bounds, center and all the other things and would greatly appreciate some help.

Comment: Thanks! What is adView representing though? Is that the view that should be centered? and What about the actualAdSize method? What is that a method of? I will up vote you as soon as I get enough reputation to do so.

Comment: What size am I getting when I should call actualAdSize?

Comment: I think you are thinking I am using a different kind of subview. My subview is a regular UIActivityIndicatorView and UILabel.

Comment: you do not to think about your view,it can be adview,it can be activityIndicatorview you just find the size of your view which you are going to place on the main view. Using 'CGSize adSize = [awView actualAdSize];' you are getting the size of the activity indicatorview which is changing his frame when you are scrolling..

Comment: ActualAdSize is not a method you can call on uiactivityindicatorview, or uiview for that matter.